# SOAP response message parsing

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I got a response message from `SOAP` that produce `wsdl` with data type

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl 
(from soapResponse.writeTo(System.out)),
```

the message more less like this

```
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <NS1:Body>
      <NS2:AccountInquiryResponse xmlns:NS2="http://www.hostname.com/AccountServices/">
         <responseCode>00</responseCode>
         <responseDetail>
            <response_code>00</response_code>
            <response_data/>
         </responseDetail>
         <accountInquiryResponseData>
            <AccountName>SJYRXS FXPUPJ IXDCYLKNU</AccountName>
            <MinimumBalance>0.00</MinimumBalance>
            <Address1>VP. FWLSJKR YJQJ 24-26 PS 2</Address1>
            <Address2>FXP FWLSJKR FXD IXKXK</Address2>
            <Address3>VJFJYSJ</Address3>
            <Address4>Vjfjysj Ecijs                 10420</Address4>
         </accountInquiryResponseData>
      </NS2:AccountInquiryResponse>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

and the question is...
how to get each fields of the response msg (data type `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl`) ???

Thank you before,

Comment: what IDE are you using? If you are using IntelliJ try this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html
You don't need to parse it manually, there's many tools to parse and create data structure from a WSDL link.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans, how about it? do I have to parse them manually? how if I do that?

Comment: checkout IDE official page. Netbeans have tutorials abount it: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html